# Divs floating wrong

Tags: html, css

How can i make the all divs to align center and stop the text menu divs from floating up to the red ones? I would like the 4 menu divs with text to be together but float left downwards.

```
<div class='man1'><img style="margin-top:20px;" src="/img/man/nokian.png" /></div>
<div class='man2'><img style="margin-top:20px;" src="/img/man/Gislaved.png" /></div>
<div class='man3'><img style="margin-top:20px;" src="/img/man/hankook.png" /></div>
<div class='man4'><img style="margin-top:20px;" src="/img/man/Gislaved.png" /></div>
<div class='man5'><img style="margin-top:20px;" src="/img/man/hankook.png" /></div>
<br />
<div class='fot1'>
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a></br>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a></br>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a>
</div>
<div class='fot2'>
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a></br>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a></br>
    <a href src="google.se">Link</a></div>
</div>
<div class='fot3'>
    <h2>Phone nbr</h2>
    <h3>
        Adress</br>
        adress</br>
        adress
    </h3>
</div>
<div class='fot4'>
    <h4>Text1</h4>
    <h4>Text2</h4></br>
    <h4>Text3</h4></br>
</div>
```

css:

```
.man1, .man2, .man3, .man4, .man5 {
    width:178px;
    height:78px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: #f00;
}

.fot1, fot2, h1, h2 {color:#fc7701}

.fot1, fot2, h1 {
}
.fot1, .fot2, .fot3, .fot4 {
    width:220px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e69wE/

Comment: Are you trying to place each image above the corresponding menu? Also, instead of using `.man1`, `.man2` etc.. Use just `.man` and then reference each one via an `id`. Much easier way of doing things.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F8fXR/ what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the 4 menu divs with text to be together but float left downwards.

I think the following snippet of CSS will achieve this:

```
.fot1 {
    clear: left;
}
```

> How can i make the all divs to align center...?

I'm sorry, can you clarify what you want here? Do you want the red DIVs arranged like so?

```
+--+  +--+  +--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+  +--+  +--+

   +--+  +--+
   |  |  |  |
   +--+  +--+
```

If that's the case, you'll want to use `display: inline-block` on the red DIVs and remove the `float: left`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e69wE/1/

Answer (score 0):

To align the divs in center try:

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

Not sure what your are asking about the menu divs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to pair the menus and the images and have them float together?

Try placing the image divs inside the corresponding `manX` divs. Then style it from there.